# How to bind event handler in contructor and call it with parameters in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code that handles ```onClick`` ok.

```
class Formi extends Component {
    onSaveTable(data, ev){
        ev.preventDefault()
        console.log(data) // logs OK
    }
    render() {
       // ...
       <button type="button" className="btn btn-success pull-left " 
           onClick= {this.onSaveTable.bind(this,data)}>Update table</button>
       //
    }
}
```

I wish to perform the bind operation in the constructor, like so:

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //...
       this.onSaveTable = this.onSaveTable.bind(this)
 }
```

and call it with parameters:

```
     <button type="button" className="btn" 
           onClick= {this.onSaveTable(this,data)}>Update table</button>
     // or using arrow function: onClick= { () => this.onSaveTable(this,data)}
```

But none of the options seems to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot send parameters if you're biding in constructor. so simply no need to bind it anywhere simply wrap it around an arrow function instead.

```
<button type="button" className="btn" 
       onClick= {(event)=>this.onSaveTable(event,data)}>Update table</button>
```

if you're using arrow functions (either you're making your class methods as arrow functions or calling them on an event by wrapping into an arrow function) you don't need to bind that function.

Comment: I like your idea - but not sure if "i do not need bind". Please note a correction to your answer: ```onClick= {(event)=>this.onSaveTable(event,data)}   ```

Comment: it's not a mistake tho you don't always need an event, but you can take it if it's needed, and yes you don't need bind if you're using arrow function, because in this scenario you're binding the class this to the function, and arrow function does that for you it takes the this of its upper scope.

Answer (score 1):

1) using bind

```
class Formi extends Component {

    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        this.onSaveTable = this.onSaveTable.bind(this);
    }
    onSaveTable(data, ev){
        ev.preventDefault()
        console.log(data) // logs OK
    }
    render() {
       // ...
       <button type="button" className="btn btn-success pull-left " 
           onClick= {(event) => this.onSaveTable(data, event)}>Update table</button>
       //
    }
}
```

2) using arrow function and currying...

```
class Formi extends Component {

    constructor (props){
        super(props);
        // No need to bind now
    }
    onSaveTable = data => ev => {
        ev.preventDefault()
        console.log(data) // logs OK
    }
    render() {
       // ...
       <button type="button" className="btn btn-success pull-left " 
           onClick= {this.onSaveTable(data)}>Update table</button>
       //
    }
}
```

Comment: With the first options the function in onClick handler is created on each render. While the second option prevent it from creating new function in each render so it's saves memory and time required to create function.

Comment: And with the use of arrow function there is no need of binding.

Comment: Thanks. Are the following similar:(1) ```onSaveTable = data => ev => {```  VS. (2)
 ```onSaveTable = (data, ev) => {```  and what are the pro's con's of those?? thanks!

Comment: Almost similar but you need to create a function like onClick= {(event) => this.onSaveTable(data, event)} and without binding you cannot access this.state or this.props or any other instance variable in the function

Answer (score 1):

No need to explicitly bind it in constructor. With use of arrow function the context of this is automatically set to the component.

Simply use :

```
<button type="button" className="btn" 
       onClick= { (ev) => this.onSaveTable(ev,data)}>Update table</button>
```